# Is there any way to use google input tool or any other language keyboard with WordPress

Tags: plugins, forms, translation, characters

I want to **type word in English** and it should be appear in other language like [Google Input Tool](http://www.google.lk/inputtools/try/) do (actually want to type English and need to convert word in to Sinhala).
Is there any plugin or any way to use [Google Input Tool](http://www.google.lk/inputtools/try/) with WordPress?